# SharePoint ribbon add button with submenu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i managed to add custom tab in sharepoint ribbon as xml definition, how can I add button with sub menu ?

Answer (score 2):

Split button is the solution of your question. Please refer the following link:

http://replicrux.com/2011/09/01/splitbutton-ribbon-control-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Cheers.

Comment: i finally found that this object is FlyoutAnchor, but i have problem when i want to place two of them

Comment: I prefer using SplitButton instead of FlyoutAnchor. But if you really wish to use FAs, then visit the link given below. It shows how to add FAs. As for the two FAs issue, you just need to change the other FA's ID attribute.

http://replicrux.com/2011/08/31/flyoutanchor-ribbon-control-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx